# For memoir class, what's equivalent of \subfigtopskip and \subfigbottomskip?

Tags: memoir, subfloats

With LaTeX `book` documentclass and `subfigure` package, the lengths `\subfigtopskip` and `\subfigbottomskip` are available.

What, if anything, are their equivalents if one uses documentclass `memoir` *without* the `subfigure` package?

**Reason for question**

What I'm trying to accomplish with `memoir` is to insert a nice, larger, space than the default between two subfigures that are positioned side-by-side, as in:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newsubfloat{figure} % needed for subfigure numbering with memoir

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\begin{center}
%
\subbottom[Point inside the ball.]{%
    \rule[2mm]{4.5cm}{5mm}% will be picture file
    }%
%
\hfill %% but want: \hspace*{something}
%
\subbottom[Point outside the disk.]{%   
    \rule[2mm]{4.5cm}{5mm}% will be picture file
    }%
%
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With `book` document class, I can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[hang,small]{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
%
\newcommand{\goodgap}{\hspace{\subfigtopskip}\hspace{\subfigbottomskip}} 
%
\begin{center}
%
\mbox{%
\subfigure[Point inside the ball.]{%
    \rule[2mm]{4.5cm}{5mm}}% will bepicture file
%
\goodgap\goodgap%
%
\subfigure[Point outside the disk.]{%
    \rule[2mm]{4.5cm}{5mm}}% picture file
}
%
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears memoir treats subfigure as a list environment, so you might try \itemsep and/or \parsep.